# Best practice to check if the user is logged in during the entire session

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, passport.js

I'm using React on the front, nodejs + express for the back, mongodb , and passportJS for the auth, and express sessions to store the session information.

Whenever someone joins my website, react is sending a request to the backend to check if the user is logged in, and then if the user is logged in it will show adapted content. The problem is that whenever someone is logged in it will first show in the nav bar a button that says "log in" and only half a second later will it be updated to "log out" because the post request that says the user is logged will resolve. What is the best practice to solve this issue? at the moment I check if the user is logged in every single time that the user navigates to a new page and it does not sound like a best practice to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `loading` state to your component. So instead of two states of `login` and `logout`, you will have `login`, `loading`, and `logout`.

This will allow you to add a new UI state for `loading`. Now it up to you to decide the UX.

UX Solution:

1. Some sites just put a giant loader and blocks the site till the app is loaded which works but is not that appealing.
2. A more modern solution is to use a `skeleton loader`. This will display a fake component while the application is `loading` (Note: NOT the whole sight needs to be in this skeleton state. It can be only the navbar while the rest of the application is displayed).
   See AntD skeleton: https://ant.design/components/skeleton/